# nginx server location mapping conflict

Tags: nginx, consul, vault

I'm trying to run vault and consul, i'm using nginx :

```
location /app {
    deny all;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://vault-consul:8500;
  }
location / {
    deny all;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://vault-app:8200;
  }
```

the problem is when I restart nginx ;
and hit `https://domai-name.com/app` it redirect me to `https://domai-name.com/ui` whichis the user interface for `vault-app` and not `vault-consul`, could you help please ?

Comment: Please also add the server config,  not just the location directive.